# I can't pass data from thread to GUI JLabel

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, jython

if **name** == '**main**':

```
demo = DesktopFrame()

demo.setLocation(30, 30)

demo.show()

comm = "COM4"

global comPort

comPort = MyCommPort()

comPort.set_port(comm)

poll = Polling(comPort)

poll.start()

poll.join()
```

This code runs (as def), My GUI comes up and allows me to change the frame content from the menu while the thread POLL sends and receives data from my serial port (fixed test loop of 20 times right now)

****GOAL:**

My goal is to have the thread update a JLabel (make it change node address) as it goes through the polling sequence.**

I've been following the jthon-swingutils2.1.1 documentation

https://pythonhosted.org/jython-swingutils/threads.html
-- Running GUI code from background threads.

from swingutils.threads.swing import callSwing

def fillInExchangeRate():

```
rate = fetchExchangeRate('USD', 'EUR')

callSwing(rateField.setValue, rate)
```

---

**PROBLEM:
Method pollUpdate(self, address)**

I can't discover the correct way for callSwing() to find my GUI JLabel [pollText] I get the following error message.

Exception in thread Thread-1:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\threading.py", line 222, in _Thread__bootstrap    self.run()
File "C:\Users\jwkel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JythonProject\src\mycommport.py", line 95, in run    self.xmit_data(self.toOutput)

File "C:\Users\jwkel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JythonProject\src\mycommport.py", line 71, in xmit_data    self.pollUpdate("Polling A")

File "C:\Users\jwkel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JythonProject\src\mycommport.py", line 66, in pollUpdate    callSwing(pollText.setValue, address)

**NameError: global name 'pollText' is not defined**

---

now for some general information about my GUI

demo = JFrame

self.menubar = JMenuBar() + 5 JMenu() + 15 JMenuItem() // all working correctly

self.add(self.mainPanel, BorderLayout.EAST)

```
contains: 

    self.mainPanel = JPanel()

    self.mainText = JTextArea()

    self.mainScroll = JScrollPane(self.mainText) +
                         
    self.mainScroll.getViewport().setView((self.mainText))

    self.mainPanel = JPanel() self.mainPanel.add(self.mainScroll)
```

self.add(self.modePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH)

```
contains:

    self.modePanel = JPanel()

    self.modeText = JLabel("Current Mode Setting : Stand Alone")

    self.pollText = JLabel("Polling Reader - ?")  ******* MY TARGET ********
```

self.add(self.panel, BorderLayout.WEST)

```
contains:

    self.panel = JPanel()

    self.panel.add(JLabel(ImageIcon(self.showImage)))
```

---

### problem code

```
from swingutils.threads.swing import callSwing 

class Polling(Thread):
    def  __init__(self, pollPort):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._pollPort= pollPort
    
    def pollUpdate(self, address):    
        callSwing(pollText.setValue, address)
        
    def xmit_data(self,sendThis):
          '''commands and data sent to readers'''
          print 'send this ',sendThis
          self.pollUpdate("Polling A")
          self._pollPort.outStream.write(sendThis)
          time.sleep(0.3)
          self._pollPort.outStream.flush()
      
    def recv_data(self):
          '''relies and requests from readers'''
          print 'recev data'  
          self.pollUpdate("Polling @")
          self.s =''
          self.text = ''
          for num in range(100):
             self.s = self._pollPort.inStream.read()
             if self.s == 10:
                break
             else:
                self.text = self.text + chr(self.s)
                print 'text = ', self.text
          return self.text
      
    def run(self):
            for i in range(20):
                time.sleep(.100)
                self.toOutput="*ATest\n" 
                self.xmit_data(self.toOutput)
                time.sleep(.300)
                self.myText = self.recv_data()
                print self.myText
```

Comment: Please fix code formatting (https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure that you provide a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I found a better example to follow and rewrote the code to use a java Class SwingWorker. All is well!